# Will Mir properly run with Intel video cards?

Tags: 13.10, mir

According to [this](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2013/09/intel-rejection-of-ubuntus-mir-patch-forces-canonical-to-go-own-way/), Intel has dropped support for Mir. What is the effect on  end user?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mir will work fine on Intel video cards.

Intel dropped *upstream* support for Mir, but since the Intel graphics drivers are open source, Ubuntu developers can add patches to re-enable Mir support in Ubuntu's version of the drivers. The move means more work for Ubuntu developers (who need to maintain these patches), but no change for the end users.

Comment: yeah, especially on GMA3600/GMA3650 (*sarcasm*)